# Is there a way to include an external Params block in a Rails Grape resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, ruby-grape

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4 and Grape.

I'd like my Grape Resources to take up a little space so that they are more readable by other developers.

In the last few days we have been integrating the Stripe API (as an example) 
and in the **params do** section of the Resources there are code blocks like this:

```
desc 'Add bank account' do
    headers API::V1::Defaults.xxxxxxx
    success API::V1::Entities::xxxxxxx
end

params do
  requires :external_account, type: Hash, allow_blank: false, desc: 'Bank account nested data' do
    requires :bank_account, type: Hash, allow_blank: false, desc: 'Bank account nested data' do
      requires :id, type: String, desc: 'Stripe token for bank account'
      requires :account_holder_name, type: String, desc: 'Bank account holder name'
      requires :account_holder_type, type: String, desc: 'Bank account holder type [individual or company]'
      optional :bank_name, type: String, desc: 'Bank name'
      requires :country, type: String, desc: 'Bank account country'
      optional :currency, type: String, desc: 'Bank account currency'
      requires :routing_number, type: String, desc: 'Bank account routing number'
      requires :name, type: String, desc: 'Bank account holders name'
      requires :status, type: String, desc: 'Bank account status'
      requires :last4, type: Integer,
                  desc: 'Account holder ID number.'
    end
    requires :client_ip, type: String, desc: 'IP address of user for Stripe service agreement'
  end
  requires :email, type: String, desc: 'Users email'
  requires :business_type, type: String, desc: 'Individual or Company'
  requires :tos_acceptance, type: Hash, allow_blank: false, desc: 'Type of Service' do
    requires :date, type: Integer, desc: 'ToS [date]'
    requires :ip, type: String, desc: 'ToS [ip]'
  end
  optional :individual, type: Hash do
    requires :first_name, type: String, desc: 'Individuals [first name]'
    requires :last_name, type: String, desc: 'Individuals [last name]'
    requires :ssn_last_4, type: String, desc: 'Individuals SSN number'
    optional :dob, type: Hash do
      requires :day, type: String, desc: 'Individuals date of birth [day]'
      requires :month, type: String, desc: 'Individuals date of birth [month]'
      requires :year, type: String, desc: 'Individuals date of birth [year]'
    end
  end
  optional :company, type: Hash do
    requires :name, type: String, desc: 'Company [first name]'
    requires :email, type: String, desc: 'Company [email]'
    requires :phone, type: String, desc: 'Company [phone]'
  end
end

# ...
oauth2
post '/' do
   # ...
end
```

How can I make that **params block** go to another file (for example inside a file in the helpers folder) and the params block can be included?

I tried to do this with `include API::V1::Helpers::my_helper` but I don't know how to insert the **params block**. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use shared params

```
module SharedParams
  extend Grape::API::Helpers

  params :pagination do
    optional :page, type: Integer
    optional :per_page, type: Integer
  end
end

class API < Grape::API
  helpers SharedParams

  desc 'Get collection.'
  params do
    use :pagination
  end

  get do
    # your logic here
  end
end
```